# Looking for a music spectrum analyzer with digital output

Tags: linux, audio, music

I'm looking for software -- compatible with Linux or WINE -- that will read a digital music file (like .mp3) and output a text file with numbers that show the loudness in each frequency band.  *I specifically **do not** want visual/graphic output.*  I want to use these numbers to add tags to .mp3 files to let music player software automatically adjust the equalization for each tune.

A plus would be a means to adjust the target equalization so I could, for example, increase the overall level of treble in my music collection; another plus would be to generate .mp3 tag data automatically.

If it has all the features I need, I would be willing to pay a reasonable price for it.

Comment: Do you want the spectrum be analyzed for the complete song, or maybe once per second / once per minute?

Comment: I would like an analysis averaged over the entire song.  I will then use these numbers to generate .mp3 tag data to automatically adjust the equalization (and volume) as I play it.  There should only be one invariant adjustment over the entire song.

Comment: @arakilian0 -- I looked at Aubio's MFCC feature and that seems to do what I want -- but I still don't know if the output is text or graphic.  Answer that and put it into the form of an answer and you can have the bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used [Aubio](https://aubio.org/), but based off some of the research [here](https://pypi.org/project/aubio/) and [here](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/aubio/latest/aubio.pdf), it seems like a good fit for what you need.

aubio is **not a visual/gui application**, aubio is an open-source programming library(python) as well as a command line tool, used to input sound files and output real audio signal data.

You work with signal data(aka sound files), [passing](https://aubio.org/manual/latest/py_io.html) the sounds to function parameters, along with other arguments, and depending on the function you used it will return a response in the form of python/aubio [data type(s)](https://aubio.org/manual/latest/py_datatypes.html). The response can be stored for dynamic use.